# getting [Cannot GET /test.html] in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm completely new to node, and i was trying to get this example to work:

[/path/to/node/server.js]

```
var connect = require('connect'); 
var serveStatic = require('serve-static'); 
var app = connect(); 
app.use(serveStatic('../angularjs'), {default: "test.html"}); 
app.listen(5000);
```

I have the file test.html inside the angularjs folder: 
[/path/to/node/angularjs/test.html]

But when i request 
    (localhost:5000/test.html) 
i'm getting in the navigator:

Cannot GET /test.html.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to be using Express 4.x which offers great functionality in node, but uses a [different initialization sequence](http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html) than this and doesn't need the connect module.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to supply `server-static` with an absolute path to `angularjs` to ensure it's searching in the expected path.

You can use the script's [`__dirname`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) as the base for it:

```
...serveStatic(__dirname + '/angularjs')...
```

Or with [`path.join()`](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2):

```
var path = require('path');
// ...

...serverStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'angularjs'))...
```

---

This is because the [file system module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), that `serve-static` is using, resolves relative paths from the [current working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) ([`process.cwd()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd)).

So, whether `../angularjs` resolves to `/path/to/node/angularjs` depends on which directory `server.js` is started from.

Currently, it could work from `/path/to/node/angularjs/`:

```sh
$ cd /path/to/node/angularjs
$ node ../server.js

# resolves: '/path/to/node/angularjs' + '../angularjs'
# to:       '/path/to/node/angularjs'
```

Or, by changing the `../` (parent directory) to `./` (current directory), it could be started from `/path/to/node` instead:

```
...serveStatic('./angularjs')...
```

```sh
$ cd /path/to/node
$ node server.js

# resolves: '/path/to/node' + './angularjs'
# to:       '/path/to/node/angularjs'
```